# Protoc Output Directory Issue - No Such File or Directory

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

I recently finished the basic tutorial for C++ [here](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/basics/) and wanted to set up a project based on the proto files from [here](https://github.com/nanoporetech/minknow_api/tree/master/proto/minknow_api). I followed a similar directory structure as the tutorial and changed up the `CMakeLists.txt` file to accommodate the new files.

I'm currently trying to just compile the `manager.proto` file. I was able to compile the file and get my server/client files, however the files are being outputted within `cmake/build/minknow_api` rather than the expected `cmake/build` folder. This meant the `make` command would return the error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/name/Documents/grpc/examples/cpp/minknow_api/cmake/build/manager.grpc.pb.cc'

clang: error: no input files
```

I read that it was because protoc outputs based on the imports of the proto file, i.e the file comes with `import minknow_api/device.proto` for instance. I copied the files from within the `cmake/build/minknow_api` into `cmake/build/` and reran `make` and it seemed to work, however, the C++ file imports as expected are searching within a `minknow_api` directory, meaning I'd have to manually edit these imports to look within the current directory instead of to then compile successfully.

I've tried experimenting with trying to get rid of the `minknow_api` from the proto imports, however had no luck and only got more import issues during compilation. It seems some files have the same names for messages etc, which means I had to keep the `minknow.somename` as the package so I can thus distinguish in the files which imported values I wanted to access. I've also tried moving files into their own directories like `instance.proto` which has `package minknow.instance` would go inside of `instance` directory, but still no luck.

I was wondering if anyone could figure out how to get rid of the `minknow_api` out of my proto imports properly so that I won't get these import and output directory issues down the track?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with C++. Because it's applicable to multiple languages, `protoc` generalizes some concepts including namespacing. The proto `package` maps to each language's packages|modules. You can tailor how this is done (at least) two ways, using proto `option`'s and by tweaking the plugin (`--cpp_out`). I suspect (!) that `protoc` **is** generating sources correctly in your case and your need to tweak the `Makefile` but, if not, there **should** be a way to configure what you want through `option` and|or `--cpp_out` (I just don't know how for C++)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I managed to get compilation working by editing the path of the output files to include the parent directory name.